# Convert timestamp to weekNumber mapReduce

Tags: java, date, hadoop, mapreduce, timestamp

I am looking to preprocess timestamps to obtain the corresponding weeknumbers using mapreduce as the dataset has hundreds of millions of instances that need to be processed. I have so far figured out that the first MR job needs to preprocess and sort each line according to timestamp as the key and the rest of the line as value.

The second job then appends the corresponding date to each timestamp object.

I however do not know how to perform the third task I need to accomplish which is to create a continuous timeline of weeknumbers .Meaning, if my minimum timestamp corresponds to the date 03/10/2000 I would like to tag this with a number 10 (indicating that this is the 10th week of the year 2000  let's assume it is if its not in this case.). Then let's say I have the next timestamp corresponding to 02/01/2011, if we assume 52 weeks in the year 2000 and that 02/01/2011 is the 5th week in 2011, I would like to tag this date as week 57 and not as week 5. I would like to know how to achieve this last step in mapreduce. Assuming I have the following input file:

```
sorted_timestamp1::date::vals....
sorted_timestamp2::date::vals...
...
...
...
sorted_timestampn::date::vals.....
```

Simple pseudocode with map and reduce in java would suffice for my case, actual code would be great also.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can separate the two problems:

1) map reduce logic:

What do you really want to calculate with map reduce. Depending on this information you have to choose the key values.

Just a guess from my side: If you want to do some aggregations on a weekly level, the mapper should take each line of input (think of line number as a key) and write out the data with new key representing the week (I'll give you some remarks in point 2.

The reducer will then have all data sets with equal week key in access and you can do whatever you want to do / aggregate and write the results out.

2) Week calculations:

Using java.util.Calendar object you can easily calculate the week of a Timestamp/Date. To get a continous week value you can calculate the week offset to a minimum reference date. To keep things simple I propose to use the 1.1. of a senceful date. To calculate the difference of weeks you can for example use

[Joda package static method Weeks.weeksBetween](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Weeks.html#weeksBetween%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,%20org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29)

If the concrete value of the "week" key is not of special interest you can also use a composite key like

year*100+week

which is much simpler to evaluate and therefore is faster. If you really need the special week timeline think about using the simple key first (just used for aggregations in map reduce) and do the more expensive week timeline evaluations later after the reducer has generated its result with much less data.

Good luck + regards

Martin